# Can this lambda be re-written as a query expression

Tags: linq

I often want just the total count(or other aggregate) of a selection, typically when cruising through some data with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) for example this query that returns the number of public enums in the core lib.

```
"".GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsPublic && t.IsEnum).Count()
```

I know that I could do something like this:

```
(from t in "".GetType().Assembly.GetTypes() 
where t.IsEnum  && t.IsPublic select t.Name).Count()
```

but maybe because of too many years in T-SQL, I find the "select t.Name" a bit off-putting.

Is there another way to get this Count without stating the "select t.Name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t).Count()
```

---

or going for terse-ness in the other direction:

```
"".GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Count(t => t.IsPublic && t.IsEnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you would need to group by t

```
         from t in "".GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
         where t.IsEnum && t.IsPublic
         group t by t into x
            select x.Count()
```

Comment: No I think that will result in 195 instances of 1.  (there appears to be 195 public enums in mscorlib 2.0.0.0)

However group t by t.IsEnum into x  does the trick.  But having said that I'm not sure if the query expression is more palatable than the lamda expression approach.  Thanks for the hint.